# What does " pretty lights and a few miles after" mean?

Tags: serenity

In *Serenity* (2005), Mr Universe speaks to Hoban, who wants him to broadcast a video:

> Mr Universe: You're going to get caught in the ion cloud. It'll play merry hob
> with your radar, but **pretty lights and a few miles after**, you'll be right in my orbit.

What does " pretty lights and a few miles after" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "pretty lights" would be an effect seen by the crew as they pass through the ion cloud on the way to Mr Universe.

The "few miles" are how far the ship will travel through the ion cloud to get to the other side and be in orbit of Mr Universe's planet.